# DGA formality via $A_\infty$

Tags: homological-algebra

Given an $A_\infty$-quasi-isomorphism $A\rightarrow B$ of dgas A and B how does one get a zig-zag of dga-quasi-isomorphisms $A\rightarrow \cdot \leftarrow \ldots \leftarrow \cdot \rightarrow B$? This is one implication in an equivalence on page 7 in B. Vallette, ALGEBRA + HOMOTOPY = OPERAD (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3245.pdf) which allows him to conclude that formality of a dga A is equivalent to the existence of an $A_\infty$-quasi-isomorphism $A\rightarrow H(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This essentially follows from the "rectification" procedure that is mentioned in the paper of Vallette (see e.g. Chapter 11 of the book *Algebraic Operads* of Loday and Vallette for more detail).

Given an augmented associative algebra $A$, you have the bar construction $BA$. It is the cofree conilpotent coalgebra on the suspension of the augmentation ideal $\bar{A}$, with some differential. In other words,
$$BA = (T^c(\Sigma \bar{A}), \partial)$$
and the differential $\partial$ is given by:
$$\partial(a_1 \otimes \dots \otimes a_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \pm a_1 \otimes \dots \otimes a_i a_{i+1} \otimes \dots \otimes a_n.$$

An $\infty$-morphism $f : A \leadsto A'$ is nothing but a morphism of dg-coalgebras $\alpha_f : BA \to BA'$. The composition of $\alpha_f$ with the projection onto $\bar{A}'$ in the bar construction is given by the maps $f_n : A^{\otimes n} \to A'$. Given the cofree nature of the underlying coalgebra of $BA'$, this is enough to specific $\alpha_f$ completely. I encourage you to check this by hand.

Then you have the cobar construction. Given a dg-coalgebra $C$, the cobar construction $\Omega C$ is a dg-algebra. It has a definition that is formally dual of the bar construction. You can find the definition in the book of Loday—Vallette for example. It's also a functor, i.e. a morphism of dg-coalgebras $C \to C'$ induces a morphism of dg-algebras $\Omega C \to \Omega C'$. Moreover, given an algebra $A$, there is a canonical quasi-isomorphism $\Omega B A \xrightarrow{\sim} A$.

So you can apply this functor to $\alpha_f : BA \to BA'$ to obtain a morphism $\Omega(\alpha_f) : \Omega BA \to \Omega BA'$. Together with the canonical quasi-isomorphisms above, you get a zigzag as expected:
$$A \xleftarrow{\sim} \Omega BA \xrightarrow{\Omega(\alpha_f)} \Omega BA' \xrightarrow{\sim} A'.$$

Moreover if $f$ is an $\infty$-quasi-isomorphism, then so is $\Omega(\alpha_f)$.

(The nice thing is, of course, that this works for any Koszul operad, so you can apply this to other kinds of algebra, e.g. commutative algebras, Lie algebras...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer! The bar-cobar resolution seems like a natural solution. I was actually thinking of something like lifting the $A_\infty$-quasi-isomorphism $A\rightarrow B$ to minimal models $M_A \rightarrow M_B$ and hoping one gets a dga-quasi-isomorphism somewhere.

Comment: @user32817 That's also possible in theory. The minimal model $M_A$ is cofibrant, so if $A$ and $B$ are quasi-isomorphic, then there must exist a direct quasi-isomorphism $M_A \to M_B$. The problem is that I can't really say how to build it from the $\infty$-morphism $A \leadsto B$.

Comment: If we have a Zig-Zag of $A_{\infty}-$quasi-isomorphisms from a dg algebra $A$ to a dg algebra $B$, then can we deduce that there is a Zig-Zag of dg quasi-isomorphisms from $A $ to $B$?

Comment: @user12580 Yes, just consider the level 1 part of the $A_\infty$-morphisms.

Comment: You mean, since $A_{\infty}-$quasi isomorphisms has a homotopy inverse, then we have a direct $A_{\infty}-$quasi isomorphism from $A$ to $B$？Then I have the question: if I know the homology algebra of $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as graded algebras, can I deduce that $A$ and $B$ are linked by quasi-isomorphisms?

Comment: @user12580 No, I mean that if $f = (f_n)_{n \ge 1} : A \leadsto B$ is an $A_\infty$-quasi-isomorphism, then $f_1 : A \to B$ is a quasi-isomorphism of chain complexes, by definition. And no, if two dgas have isomorphic homologies, it does not follow that they are quasi-isomorphic as dgas. It's usually a difficult question to know whether two dgas are quasi-isomorphic, even if they have isomorphic homologies (if their homologies are not isomorphic, then clearly they cannot be quasi-isomorphic).

Comment: But Since we have $H^*(A)\rightarrow A$ and $H^*(B)\rightarrow B$. So the question is whether $H^*(A)\rightarrow H^*(B)$ is an $A_{\infty}$ morphism provided they are isomorphic as graded algebras.

Comment: @user12580 The problem is that in $H^*(A) \to A$, you do not consider $H^*(A)$ with its dga structure. You consider it with an $A_\infty$-structure induced by Massey products in $A$. Same in $B$. Even if $H^*(A) = H^*(B)$ as algebras, it does not follow that the Massey products will be the same.

Comment: If the two dg algebras $A$ and $B$ are derived equivalent with A sent to B, then is it true that $A$ and $B$ are quasi isomorphic? I don’t know if we can recover Massey product from the derived category.